# Image.setSrc() not updating the image everytime

Tags: image, sencha-touch, base64, sencha-touch-2

I have spent 2 nights on this problem , almost searched everywhere but haven't found a proper working solution yet. If you could please help with the below mentioned problem:

I have a container with `Hbox` layout showing a picture on the right when one of the item from the nested list on the left is selected
this works perfectly fine the first time I use that page, it shows all the images on tap to all the nested list items,
but if I go back to my previous page and try to come back it shows the list but the image is not shown on selecting anything .

I am using `base64` string in `SET.SRC()` function as I have to store these images locally and the only solution I have figured out was to store in local storage which needs the image `base64` string to store it.

I saw a solution in this other forum https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthr...t-update-image. 
but apparently if I try to add anything to the `base64` url of the image it will not load the image anyway

I am not sure if this is something with the browsers cache or something else, but haven't found a solution and cant go to next step without it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you destroy the current page when you move back to another page?

Comment: yep i guess that was the problem

Comment: Could you +1 my answer, if it helped you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

On my main page of navigation view i turned `AutoDestroy:false` which wasn't letting my previous page visits to destroy
So turned it `AutoDestroy:true` and it worked